# PHP Paytm checksum failed while PEON/IPN response

Tags: php, paytm

I am using Paytm payment gateway and its working fine.But it always failed(Checksum failed) while PEON/IPN response.Can anyone assist on this problem?

Comment: I suggest you contact tech support for paytm.

Comment: yes.but i thought any fixes available..